# Hook to import entity data in custom module installation in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, hooks, entities, installation

What would be 'the best' hook function to use in the custom module installation to import entity data? This is supposed to be a one-time activity during the module installation only, after entity schema is built in the database and entities are initialized (to be able to use Entity API in the data import).

Answer (score 1):

For one time import of data, when installing a module, use [`hook_install`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_install/7).  This can be used to populate the database just after tables are created, provided your module also implements [`hook_schema`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7).

You do not want to use 
[`hook_enable`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_enable/7).  If you used this, the database would be re-populated every time the module was re-enabled after being temporary disabled.

Comment: Thank you, [hook_install](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_install/7) definitely looks more proper, and it seems to run after custom modules are loaded as well, so can use definitions of custom entities with Entity API.

Answer (score 0):

... just found, could be hook_enable() if I'm not mistaken about its usage